# Change appearance of ConvexHullMesh

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh

I'm struggling to understand the behaviour of `ConvexHullMesh` (or rather the non-behaviour). I have a polygon `p`

```
p = { {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, 1/2}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}
```

which I can display in a nice way like by e.g.:

```
Show[Graphics[{LightBlue, EdgeForm[Gray], Polygon[p]}],  Graphics[ {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[#]}] & /@ p]
```

Now I construct the convex hull

```
q = ConvexHullMesh[p];
```

which displays a somewhat featureless rectangle. Having a closer look at `q`

```
q // InputForm
```

I get

> BoundaryMeshRegion[{{0., 0.}, {0., 1.}, {1., 0.}, {1., 1.}}, {Line[{{1, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 2}, {2, 1}}]},  Method -> {"EliminateUnusedCoordinates" -> True, DeleteDuplicateCoordinates" -> Automatic, "VertexAlias" -> Identity, "CheckOrientation" -> True, "CoplanarityTolerance" -> Automatic, "CheckIntersections" -> Automatic, "BoundaryNesting" -> {{0, 0}}, "SeparateBoundaries" -> False, "PropagateMarkers" -> True, "Hash" -> 1136472811504667718}]

so the obvious (?) idea is to replace the head of `q` (i.e. `BoundaryMeshRegion`) by a suitably defined function `f` that uses the argument to display the convex hull in a 'nicer' way. Ignoring the exact implementation of `f`, the 'usual' way fails, as

```
f @@ q
```

just redisplays the rectangle. `Head[q]` gives the expected `BoundaryMeshRegion`, but `Apply` (or `@@`) somehow fails to replace the head. Similarly, the alternative `q[[1]]` to access the argument of the head fails.

What am I missing?

Or to be more precise:

- How do I change the appearance of `ConvexHullMesh`?
- Why does the above solution not work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While the answers provided so far are nice, it seems like there should be easier ways to achieve this. And there are, I will show two ways: 1) Keeping your `ConvexHullMesh` as a `BoundaryMeshRegion` object and (2 converting to a `Graphics` object.

```
SeedRandom[0]
pts = RandomReal[4, {200, 3}];
chull = ConvexHullMesh[pts];
```

First we use `HighlightMesh` with no need to recreate the `MeshRegion`:

```
HighlightMesh[chull, {Style[0, Directive[PointSize[0.015], Red]], 
  Style[1, Thin, Blue], Style[2, Opacity[0.5], Yellow]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note the use of `Style` to style the various dimensions (`0` for vertices, `1` for edges and `2` for facets. Also note that this object is still a `BoundaryMeshRegion` and you can compute other nice mesh-related properties from it.

Now the `Graphics` object approach.

```
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates[chull], {PointSize[0.02], Red,       
  MeshCells[chull, 0], Blue, MeshCells[chull, 1], Green, MeshCells[chull, 2]}], 
  Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note the use of the already available properties of the `MeshRegion`. No need to use `Show` here.

Comment: @RunnyKine...thanks for this wonderful and illustrative, general (and best answer) +1...mine was a hack on the fly...

Comment: @ubpdqn, Thanks for the up-vote. I thought this was worth sharing since it's not obvious at first how to style these `Mesh` objects directly.

Comment: I am still negotiating MMA10 and the computational geometry features...so very happy to learn more.,,so excellent answer

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. +1

Answer (score 8):

`Show` allows you to convert to Graphics object:

```
Graphics[Show[ConvexHullMesh[p]][[1]] /. {Directive[x_] :> 
    Directive[{Red, EdgeForm[{Black, Thickness[0.02]}]}]}]
```

[image]

Or perhaps a little more interesting:

```
pts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {50, 2}];
g = Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[pts]}];
ch = Show[ConvexHullMesh[pts]][[1]] /. {Directive[x_] :> 
     Directive[{Yellow, EdgeForm[{Black, Thickness[0.02]}]}]};
Show[Graphics[ch], g]
```

[image]

Comment: Now that is cool. Thanks a lot. Now, any idea why my 'Apply'-idea doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

> Why the above solution (`f@@q`) doesn't work?

Because a `MeshRegion` is an `AtomQ`.

> How do I change the appearance of `ConvexHullMesh`?

Because

> The convex hull region is the smallest convex region that includes the points

the computed and returned `ConvexHullMesh` is of course correct. Because you are computing the convex hull, maybe it's because you are interested to show the input list of points and their convex hull. You can use `Show` to combine directly a `MeshRegion` with another `Graphics`.

Maybe you are interested to `DelaunayMesh`, related with but different from `ConvexHullMesh` (returns a `MeshRegion` instead of a `BoundaryMeshRegion`).

```
p = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, 1/2}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}};
q = ConvexHullMesh[p];
{Show[q, Graphics@Point@p], HighlightMesh[DelaunayMesh[p], Style[0, Red]]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

```
p = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, 1/2}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}};

Show[

 ConvexHullMesh[p],

 HighlightMesh[
  MeshRegion[p, Polygon[Range@Length@p],
   MeshCellStyle -> {2, All} -> Opacity[0.5, Orange]],
  Labeled[0, "Index"]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While converting to a [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) object or using [`HighlightMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HighlightMesh) may be more flexible, you don't need to. To obtain a similar style as the OP [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) object, one could just add options to the [`ConvexHullMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexHullMesh) call. Here is the OP [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) object:

```
Show[
    Graphics[{LightBlue, EdgeForm[Gray], Polygon[p]}], 
    Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[p]}]
]
```

[image]

And here's a similar output using [`ConvexHullMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexHullMesh):

```
ConvexHullMesh[
    p,
    MeshCellStyle->{
        0->Directive[PointSize[Large],Red],
        1->Gray,
        2->LightBlue
    }
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For some settings of the option `PlotTheme` various cells are more *visible*:

```
Grid @ Partition[Labeled[ConvexHullMesh[p, ImageSize -> 250, Frame -> False, 
   PlotTheme -> #], Style[#, 24], Top]& /@ 
 {"Business", "Web", "Marketing", "Classic","Scientific","Detailed", 
  "Points","Lines", "Polygons"}, 3]
```

[image]