# Plot region from given coordinates

Tags: plotting

How can I connect given coordinates and create figure from it? Can I fill it with colour?
I tried:

`Line[{a[[1]], a[[2]], a[[3]], a[[4]], a[[5]], a[[1]]}]`

where `a` is my list. It doesnt look good.

`a` consists of coordinates in 2D `{x,y}` pairs. I want to connect all points to form a region/space/figure and fill that region with colour.

Comment: We need more information. Provide an example list `a`. What do you mean by "fill it with color"? - the line has a color? - color fill between the line and the axis? What do you mean by "it doesn't look good"? Did you embed the `Line` in a `Graphics` object? Etc.

Comment: a consists of coordinates {{-0.9504, -0.31103}, {-0.946885, -0.321572}, {0.848087, 0.529857}, {0.998268, -0.0588254}}

I want to connect them to form a region/space/figure and fill that region with colour.

Comment: Please add relevant information to your post by clicking the grey edit button at the bottom of the post. In addition, please format your code correctly.

Comment: Done. Can you answer my question please?

Comment: Graphics[{Blue, Polygon@a}]

Comment: it doesnt always works. For some values sometimes it creates figures like this http://i.imgur.com/tAeOCSa.png?1

I want it to create geometric figures

Comment: Either re-order the points so that it works or possibly you can use `ConvexHullMesh@a`.

Comment: I am using random points for my list a, so it needs to work for any combination. ConvexHull seems to do the job :) but can I change the colour? thx

Comment: See [this question and answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58049/change-appearance-of-convexhullmesh).

Comment: See also [How to ensure that Polygon\[list\] plots a simple polygon?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9406/484) and [Rebuild a polygon so it doesn't self intersect](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48091/484)

Comment: Found the solution by combining new commands I found in google. The answer is:

Graphics[Line[{a[[Last[FindShortestTour[a]]]]}]]

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun

```
(*psuedo-data*)
data = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {5, 2}];

(*process*)
Manipulate[
  Graphics[{col, Polygon @ pts}],
  {{pts, data}, Locator},
  {{col, Green, "Color"}, {Green, Blue, Red}}]
```

[image: polygon]

Comment: Omg 1k reputation!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid polygons whose edges cross themselves, try this:

```
ConvexHullMesh[a]
```

For instance:

```
a = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 2}];

Graphics[Polygon[a]]
```

[image]

```
ConvexHullMesh[a]
```

[image]

or

```
ConvexHullMesh[a, PlotTheme -> "Lines", MeshCellStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

Note that `FindShortestTour` does not work:

```
a = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, .1}, {2, .1}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {1.5, 1}};

Graphics[Line[a[[FindShortestTour[a][[2]]]]]]
```

[image]

which is not convex.

Comment: Why is it a problem if the `FindShortestTour` solution is not convex?

Comment: There is no reason the shortest tour need be convex...  The shortest tour must go through *every* point, which includes those in the interior of the convex hull.  Hence the shortest tour will rarely be convex.

Comment: Yes, that's fine, but why is that a problem? You say this approach "does not work", but the asker didn't ask for a convex figure.

Comment: Yes he did... when he wrote:  "it doesn't always work. For some values sometimes it creates figures like this i.imgur.com/tAeOCSa.png?1 I want it to create geometric figures."

Comment: @David that's self intersection, but non convex is probably fine.